Show element when in viewport on scroll detect div
I have elements that are displayed as I scroll down but they are identified by number from 400,350 but how could I replace the numbers with a class within a div
so you don't have to depend on the scroll number but on the class nested in the div
not exactly how to make it work without having errors
document.getElementById('menu_escritorio');

// OnScroll event handler

const onScroll = () => {

  // Get scroll value

  const scroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop;

  // If scroll value is more than 0 - add class

  if (scroll > 400) {
    menu_escritorio.classList.add("scrolled");
    $(".sub-title").addClass("fixbar");


  } else {
    menu_escritorio.classList.remove("scrolled")
        $(".sub-title").removeClass("fixbar");

  }

  if (scroll > 350) {

        $(".imagendeproducto").addClass("fixed2");
        $(".detail-padding-left").addClass("fixed3");


  } else {

        $(".imagendeproducto").removeClass("fixed2");
        $(".detail-padding-left").removeClass("fixed3");

}


}
// Use the function
window.addEventListener('scroll',onScroll);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

an answer to help me identify my problem
